# "Wrong model type for classification" in regression problems in R-Caret

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to use various prediction algorithms from the Caret package in R for regression problem that is my target variable is continuous. Caret thinks classification is the appropriate class of the problem and when I pass any of the regression models, I get an error message that says "wrong model type for classification". For reproducibility, let's see with the [Combined Cycle Power Plant Data Set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00294/). The data is in CCPP.zip. Let's predict power as a function of the other variables. Power is a continuous variable.

```
  library(readxl)
  library(caret)
  power_plant = read_excel("Folds5x2_pp.xlsx")
  apply(power_plant,2, class)   # shows all columns are numeric

  control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=5)

  my_glm <- train(power_plant[,1:4], power_plant[,5],
           method = "lm",
           preProc = c("center", "scale"),
            trControl = control)
```

The image below is my screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason `caret` gets confused by tibbles, which is the tidyverse variant of a data frame that `read_excel` returns. By converting it to a simple data frame before giving it to caret, everything works:

```
library(readxl)
library(caret)
power_plant = read_excel("Folds5x2_pp.xlsx")
apply(power_plant,2, class)   # shows all columns are numeric

power_plant <- data.frame(power_plant)
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=5)

my_glm <- train(power_plant[,1:4], power_plant[,5],
                method = "lm",
                preProc = c("center", "scale"),
                trControl = control)

my_glm
```

yielding:

```
Linear Regression 

9568 samples
   4 predictor

Pre-processing: centered (4), scaled (4) 
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 5 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 8612, 8612, 8611, 8612, 8612, 8610, ... 
Resampling results:

  RMSE      Rsquared 
  4.556703  0.9287933

Tuning parameter 'intercept' was held constant at a value of TRUE
```

Comment: Actually I found this in other circumstances, too, e.g. when trying to use glm with tibble it complained about levels of some factor so I had to ```as.data.frame(unclass(my_tibble))``` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I get a similar error when I try to use formula = y ~ x, works great just omitting the named variable and using y ~ x.

Comment: can you post it as new question instead asking question in answer?